# How to activate Entity Framework Extensions license in global.asax file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-extensions

I bought license for Entity Framework Extensions. I added LicenseName and LicenseKey to app.config file and tried to activate license in global.asax.
This is activation code from their documentation:

```
    Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.LicenseManager.AddLicense([licenseName], [licenseKey]);
```

However I am getting error about expiration which is not true in my case. Does anybody knows how to properly setup license in global.asax? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your global.asax  file format. Where did you add the particular code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have updated inside the Application_Start in global.asax to activate your license.

***Note:*** Add the license before the first call to the library. Otherwise, the library will be enabled using the evaluation period.